# Is there anyway to store prompted inputs into a .json file and reuse the stored inputs from the json file in the next session/process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm creating an account generator using puppeteer and there's certain user inputs that are needed and I have it prompt the user to input the necessary variables and I was wondering, is it possible to store these inputs into a json file and then pull the stored inputs from the json file and reuse it for the next session rather than having to input the required variables over and over again after every new process. The code below is the package I have required and the following variables that are prompted.

````
const prompt = require("prompt-sync") ({sigint: true });
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const request = require('request');
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const { ImapFlow } = require('imapflow');
const random_useragent = require('random-useragent');
const { scrollPageToBottom } = require('puppeteer-autoscroll-down')
const { scrollPageToTop } = require('puppeteer-autoscroll-down')
const { Webhook, MessageBuilder } = require('discord-webhook-node');

const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

( async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: false, // false = Shows Browser | true = Browser Not Shown
        executablePath: `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`,
        userDataDir: `/Users/senpai/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
        args: [
                `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`,
                `--enable-blink-feautres=IdleDetection`,
                `--window-size=1920,1080`,
                `--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process`, 
                `--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=true`
        ]
    });

    // User Inputs
        let webhook = prompt ("Input Discord Webhook: ");
        let catchall = prompt ("Input Your Catchall - Exp: catchall.com: ");```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already imported the built-in `fs` module, so you could use it to check whether there's an existing JSON file to be used, otherwise prompt the user, and then store the values in the said JSON file. Something like this:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });

const filename = "values.json";

function getValues() {
  if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename));
  }

  const values = {
    webhook: prompt("Input Discord Webhook: "),
    catchall: prompt("Input Your Catchall - Exp: catchall.com: "),
  };

  fs.writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify(values));

  return values;
}

const { webhook, catchall } = getValues();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer, I just wanted to double check so I fully understand the function. so you established the function 'getValues()' and the if statement will then check if there's such a file or data within the file, if it's not there, it will then prompt the user the following prompts then store it into the 'values.json'?

Comment: @JediSZN You're exactly right!